# Install Laravel Jetstream with Vue JS 2

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

Jetstream by default installs inertia with Vue JS version 3 even though we can select the inertia version when just installing Inertia.

Few of the Vue plugins I have planned to use still do not have Vue3 support. So is it possible to install Jetstream with Vue JS 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you can use old jetstream version.
jetstream version 2.2.0 support with vue3 before that it will support vue2. But it might contain some bugs.
To install jetstream with vue2 run comment on terminal

```
laravel new hello
cd hello
```

edit composer.json `"laravel/jetstream": "^2.1",`
then run `composer install; php artisan jetstream:install inertia` on terminal.
And finally run `npm install; npm run dev; php artisan migrate` on terminal.

Answer (score 4):

@bapi is right, you need to use an older version of `Laravel Jetstream`.

You need to use the exact jetstream which is `"laravel/jetstream": "2.1.4"` instead of `"laravel/jetstream": "^2.1"` which installs `inertiajs` with `vuejs2`.

See changelogs here from the official repo https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/blob/2.x/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: It seems like it can't now

Comment: @Fahmi take note of the version, use  `2.1.4` instead of `^2.1`. Make sure to omit the caret. On my end I used `~2.1.4` and run `composer update` to force updates when you have ran `composer install` already.

Answer (score 3):

Formatted steps:

Follow these exact steps to solve the issue on a **fresh** project

1. add `laravel/jetstream": "2.1.4"` to your `"require"` dependencies in your `composer.json` file
2. run `composer update`
3. run `php artisan jetstream:install inertia`
4. run `npm install`
5. run `npm run dev`
6. run `php artisan migrate`

Now your Laravel 8 project should have Laravel Jetstream install with vue 2

Comment: So kikuyu1 says bapi is right but you say is answer is correct but bapi is not right.. And yet you pretty much copy pasted his answer.. Hmmm.. Anyways all answer here are the same, while yours has a better formatting it doesn't add anything meaningfull and you should have proposed an edit of the accepted answer