# I want to install Laravel Jetstream with inertia-vue2

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

So is it possible to install Jetstream with **Inertia-Vue2**?

```
php artisan jetstream:install inertia
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Laravel Jetstream with Vue JS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149335/install-laravel-jetstream-with-vue-js-2)

Answer (score -1):

Of course, you can install Jetstream with Inertia-Vue2. Not installing with `php artisan jetstream:install inertia`. You must edit composer.json file and add the version 2 of Jetstream, after `composer install`.

See this comment:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67151050/10699475